# I am getting (loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00) for all epochs after training the model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I made a simple model to train my data set which consists of (210 samples and each sample consists of a numpy array of 22 values)
and `x_trian` and `y_trian` look like:

[image]

and this is my simple code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils import shuffler

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

import io
dset = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['1-210.csv']))

y= dset.Readernumber
x=dset.drop('Readername',axis=1)

#the split ratio of 80:20. The 20% testing data set is represented by the 0.2 at the end.
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)

x_train= np.asarray(x_train).astype('float32')
y_train = np.asarray(y_train).astype('float32')
y_train, x_train = shuffle(y_train, x_train)

#create the model #input_shape=(23,)
model = Sequential([
    Dense(units=4,input_shape=(22,), activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=16, activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=10, activation='softmax')
])

#get the model ready for training is call the compile() function on it.
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) 

#train it using the fit() function. 
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

And this is what I'm getting for all the epochs :

[image]

I will be grateful to anyone who can help me!

Comment: The reason must be there: ```y_train, x_train = shuffle(y_train, x_train)```when doing this you are simply breaking the relationship between your features set and your target. Actually I do not see where you define x_train nor y_train

Comment: i forgot this line sorry and i undated it above
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)

Comment: great! so any reason for this line ```y_train, x_train = shuffle(y_train, x_train```? from my understanding this is causing your model not to be able to learn anything since it adds literally pure randomness to your X, y mapping

Comment: thank you julio, unfortunately the code give me another error and i don't know why,how ever it was working will, i gives me "could not convert string to float: '9 0.559884" for this line "x_train= np.asarray(x_train).astype('float32')"

Comment: It seems like you have mixed data types in your x matrix, all the inputs should be numerical and in here you have a value that could not  be converted into float '9 0.559884, it might be because it seem there are a space between the first 9 and the consecutive 0, try to clean this. Interestings this error was not shown before

Comment: really many thanks julio it has been fixed but after i remove the line of shuffle() as you told me i still have the same error " loss: nan" for all epochs.

Comment: I just noticed ,batch_size=0, can you remove or change this for a value greater to or equal to 10?

Comment: yes i removed it but still gives me the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment -- where this would be more applicable -- but your `y_train` is class encoded (e.g., this sample's label is class `1`), which is a single output. When your data are fed into the model w/ 10 output nodes, the model doesn't know what to do considering your `y_train` has 1 output for each sample.

A solution would be to one-hot encode your outputs (e.g., if your sample's label is class `1`, it would be represented as `[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`). Sklearn has a convinient [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder) to make the preprocessing simple. Now you have 10 outputs for each sample and the model can understand what's going on. Hopefully this helps

Comment: did you mean that i should encode the y_trian before i feed it to the  fit function ?
using this way : 
enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(y_train)
onehotlabels = enc.transform(y_train).toarray()
 ,  but it always gives me this error 
Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: Regards! Robert

Comment: Yes. You need to reshape your arrays. For each sample, it should initially be something like `(,10)`, but it needs to either be reshaped to `(1,10)` or `(10,1)`, I can't remember off the top of my head right now. Either way, it can be accomplished using the array's `reshape` command

Comment: i tried  reshape(10,1) and reshape(1,10) it always gives me " ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 189 into shape (1,10)"
then i tried " reshape(189,10) still gives me "  ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 189 into shape (189,10) "

Comment: That's for each sample. Reshape(189,1,10) or reshape(189,10,1) for all your data

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you Robert, but it still gives me 
"cannot reshape array of size 189 into shape (189,10,1)" or "cannot reshape array of size 189 into shape (189,1,10)"

Comment: It's no problem.Initially, your `y_train` should be something like `(,189)` with your class encoding. After you one-hot encode your classes, your shape should be `(189,10)` (e.g., your data should look like `[[0,0,0,1,...], [0,1,0,0,...],...]]`). Try training it w/ that shape. If it fails, you can reshape your data to be a shape `(189,10,1)` or `(189,1,10)` and it should run then.

Comment: many thanks Robert! i finally encoded it using one_hot as you told me but the fit function gives my anther error which is "logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,10] and labels shape [320]"

Comment: many thanks Robert! i finally encoded it using one_hot as you told and instead of using loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy' i use loss='categorical_crossentropy' and finally the error has been gone, many thanks again and regards!

Answer (score 0):

you should one_hot target(y) before model.fit & give it in training in such a form

```
y= tf.one_hot(y,10,)
```

you've got ok, just display results of each batch training:

```
history= model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32)
print(history.history['accuracy'])
print(history.history['loss'])
```

and can evaluate your model

```
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test,  verbose=2)
print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)
```

and at the end when predicting - choose from probabilities the best

```
predicted = model.predict(x)
Y2 = predicted.argmax( axis = 1)
print(Y2)
```

p.s. your 1st Dense better use *Dense(units=64,..)*